# contact added in roster using subscribed then also not showing contact presence using strophe.js

Tags: backbone.js, xmpp, strophe, user-presence

I'm learning xmpp with strophe.js , backbone.

I'm developing friend request sending functionality in my web site.
For this i have written following code in backbone :

```
            var statusClass = constants.loggedInUserDetails.Status;
            var user1JIDXmpp = params.userID + 'xmppExtensionName: "@exterprise1.com/foobar"';
            connection.send($pres({ to: user1JIDXmpp, type: "subscribed" }));

            if (statusClass == 'busy') {
                connection.send($pres({ to: user1JIDXmpp, type: "dnd" }).c("show").t("dnd"));
            }
            else if (statusClass == 'available') {
                connection.send($pres({ to: user1JIDXmpp, type: "available" }).c("priority").t("1"));
            }
            else if (statusClass == 'offline') {
                connection.send($pres({ to: user1JIDXmpp, type: "offline" }).c("status").t("unavailable"));
            }
```

and in strophe.roster.js written code for added contact in roster when received presence.

Issue I'm facing is : **after this process if any contact changes presence then it is not notifying to contact which is been subscribed in roster.**

*It is notifying contact presence only after subscribed contact login again.*

How to solve this problem ? Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Is the subscription status "both"?

Comment: @MarkS : actually I'm new to strophe.js and xmpp. I'm trying using google only. I'm reading about xmpp and trying some things. But did not get success yet.